# Similar articles based on tag weight

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, tags

I would like to develop a new feature at one project I am managing. It would be a similar article listing for left and bottom panels. The project is developed in Laravel.

When a user views an article, there are a few similar articles displayed on bottom and in left panel, currently ordered by views and they are pulled from the same category as currently viewed article.

We want to have more precise article picking for similar articles, based on this principle:

An editor can create a Tag in administration, and assign a numerical value (weight) to the tag. Multiple tags can be assigned to an article.

Whe have many-to-many relationship here, between Article and Tag tables (with pivot table).

When user views particluar article, I would like to compose a query to pick similar articles based on the tags assiociation and their weight.

For example, when we have a tag Home, with weight 20, Furniture with 15, Kids with 10 etc. The query gets the tags for current article and starts comparing them with other articles tags, and will order them based on sum of tag weights.

Example:

```
Article A : Home 20, Furniture 15, Garden 10
Article B : Garden 10, Home 20, Kids 5
Article C : Garden 10, Kids 5
Article D : Furniture 15, Kids 5
```

We are viewing Article B, we have these same tag associations with other articles:

```
Article A: Home 20 -> Weight score: 20
Article C: Garden 10, Kids 5 -> Weight score: 15
Article D: Kids 5 -> Weight score: 5
```

These articles are then ordered by their score descening and showed in left column in this order.

Since I am working only with Eloquent so far, I can't wrap my head around a raw sql query that can do this. Or any other Eloquent way.

Does anybody have idea if this can be done the Eloquent way, with a bit of raw sql, or completely raw sql ?

I understand that this query is complex, so I will be storing it in Redis cache for an hour. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the query builder? I think it's the easiest solution in any case when working with complex SQL queries.

Here's an example(havn't tried it myself and just assuming that the orderBy will work):

```
DB::table('articles')->
    select(
        'articles.name as a_name',
        'tags.name as t_name',
        'article_tag.weight as p_weight'
    )->join(
        'article_tag'
        function($join)
        {
            $join->on(
                'articles.id',
                '=',
                'article_tag.articles_id'
            )->orderBy(
                'article_tag.weight'
            );
        }
    )->join(
        'tags'
        function($join)
        {
            $join->on(
                'tags.id',
                '=',
                'article_tag.tags_id'
            );
        }
    )->groupBy(articles.name)->get();
```

That should return the data as an array with the

Eloquent:
Have you tried the Model::with statement?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll try it soon and will come back with results.